# Where do you get Ammo for Cryolator?

Tags: fallout-4

Do any vendors sell ammo?

Can the gun be modified to use different ammo (like the alien blaster)?

Comment: I don't understand why so many Fallouters are worried about finding Cryo Cells. The weapon is great in the beginning, but once you've perked up Gun Nut, Rifleman and found the other signature weapons, there is no need to freeze enemies anymore. Take the Spray and Pay weapon out for some play time, you'll soon forget all about that Popsicle gun!

Comment: I have an Explosive Combat shotgun so I don't really care about any other weapons. But it's always good to know for other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ammunition you're looking for is Cryo Cells. You can get these from weapons vendors such as Arturo in Diamond City.

[image: cryo cells from arturo]

Comment: Can it be modified to use different ammo?

Comment: No, it can't...