# Where can I get rarer ammo in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I am having troubles finding the more lucrative ammo, used for weapons such as the Cryolator. I am playing on Xbox One.

Where can I acquire harder-to-get ammunition?

Comment: Cryolator Ammo - Diamond City mechant.  [Fat Man Mini Nuke locations](http://mmgn.com/xboxone/articles--fallout-4-fat-man-and-mini-nuke-location-guid)

Comment: Ive tried editing this question, as you should be limiting a question to one question. Asking for sources for rare ammo should get you both answered, while providing more utility. Upon looking at the link @Dom provides, I feel this definitely should be two separate questions, with one question solely for Fat Man locations.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243761/where-can-i-find-more-fat-man-mini-nukes-in-fallout-4/243762#243762

Comment: I was going to provide the Cryolator answer, but if thats all your after, that has already been answered here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243271/where-do-you-get-ammo-for-cryolator

Answer (score 5):

The Commonwealth Weaponry store run by Arturo in Diamond City stocks all kinds of ammunition, including fusion cells, plasma packets and cryo ammo. This is the same with the vendor in Goodneighbor.

For finding this ammo out in the wild, in general you're going to want to be fighting against the enemies that use each kind of weapon (so for example, you'll find lots of ammo in the Institute and fusion cells drop off synths).

See also: [Where do you get Ammo for Cryolator?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243271/52800)

Comment: Is his stock based on your current level?

Answer (score 1):

Having the scrounger perk is always helpful for finding the less common ammo types and of course you can usually buy most ammo types from merchants. For the Cryolator specifically think you have to primarily rely on merchants. I have asked a few people and they said they haven't seen any cryo ammo drop from random boxes so there is probably little chance or no chance at all of finding it while scavenging.

Comment: I've found cryolater cores on, I believe, a protectron somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For the Fat Man gun, the only reliable source of mini-nukes I'm aware of are Super Mutant Suiciders. If you kill one without setting off the nuke it it's hand, the nuke becomes a loot item.