# Where can I find more Fat Man mini-nukes in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I just found the Fat Man, and the mini-nukes can be hard to come by. I recall feeling they were a lot more scripted in previous Fallout titles, rather then being acquired at stores, or created. Where can I go to find more mini-nukes?

Comment: Given the proximity of Fat Man launchers and the mini nukes, it might be wise to broaden this to "where are the fat man launchers and mini nukes". Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug, however after completing the *Secret of Cabot House* quest chain, the Fat Man and mini nuke in the basement of the **Cabot House** in central Boston will

1) no longer be flagged as owned, so you are free to take both

And more importantly

2) Respawn immediately when you fast travel away and then return to the house.

(In addition to the Fat Man and mini nuke, there's two steamer chests and a Master locked safe full of guns ammo and pre-war money, a Gamma Gun, and tons of highly valuable junk and aid items scattered around the house. It's a gold mine.)

Comment: Can you provide more infotmation on the respawn? Ie. If there is an automatic respawn here, and this can be used for farming?

Comment: @Timelord64 done. It's immediate and automatic. Highly lucrative, infinite mini nukes and other random ammo.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, [Super Mutant Suiciders](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Super_mutant_%28Fallout_4%29#Super_mutant_suicider) carry a mini-nuke. Unfortunately, their main goal is to kill you with it, so you have to kill them before they use it in order to loot it from their body.

[A handy guide](http://mmgn.com/xboxone/articles--fallout-4-fat-man-and-mini-nuke-location-guid) at [Xbox.MMGN.com](http://mmgn.com/xboxone/) provides an excellent list of locations hosting a Fat-Man and some mini-nukes. Finding a Fat-Man usually suggests that there should be at least one mini-nuke nearby, but this is speculation from personal experience.

Please note that the article also features a handy map for pin pointing these locations. For the most part, these are locations you will likely come across, anyway. For some, you will need to have completed various quest steps, to access the location.

- **Robotics Disposal Ground**: Near a pile of tires, at the east entrance.
- **Malden Center**: Found on the station, near an ammo crate, to the south on the first floor.
- **Revere Satellite Array**: There is a Super Mutant Suicider at this location.
- **Prydwen**: There are 5 mini-nukes on level 2.
- **Fort Strong**: Multiple nukes across the location.
- **South Boston Military Checkpoint**: Inside the truck trailer, locked behind an Expert terminal.
- **Gunners Plaza**: Two mini-nukes can be found on level 2, in the southern area of the map.
- **Ticonderoga Safehouse**: A mini-nuke and a Fat Man are located on the sixth floor.
- **D.B. Technical High School**: In the basement, and on level 1.
- **The Castle**: In the western point of the star-like structure.

Comment: Furthermore you can't craft ammo: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242879/is-it-possible-to-create-your-own-ammo But are there merchants who sell ammo for Fat-Man?

Comment: I've had the weapon shop at Diamond City offer to sell me Mini Nukes I think (at the same they tried to sell me a Legendary Fat Man that launched "an additional projectile").

Comment: It's sooooooo tempting to just shoot the nuke on the suicider and make him go boom though.  Especially if he is near other mutants

Comment: There's one in Secret Vault 81 in final mole rat spawn room with the dirt floor (near the exit)

Answer (score 0):

These are the locations where I was able to find mini-nukes on my play through.

1. Arcjet Systems (confirmed with Danse)
2. Boston Mayoral Shelter (Part of research patrol BoS quest)
3. Greenetech Genetics (Follow the Courser)
4. Cabot House (Any of Imogene Took A Lover or helping Cabot quests)

Please note Arcjet, Mayoral shelter, and Greenetech have atleast 2 mini nukes.

Answer (score 0):

The Satellite place near the robotics disposal ground has one inside. All you need to do is unlock a terminal and inside is one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have master lock picking break into the room in the pyrdwen and there's two in there plus a fatman and several scattered downstairs from there

Comment: Is this the same location referred to in the accepted answer as "Prydwen: There are 5 mini-nukes on level 2"?

Answer (score 0):

If you go in arturo`s house, he has a mini nuke on his table near his bed, downstairs

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for contributing! On Stack Exchange, we generally prefer that answers are complete, so that they can stand alone. Obviously, one spot where one can find a min-nuke is not a complete answer. This would probably be better as a comment on the accepted answer, so it could be added to the list, or you could just edit it in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In Diamond City, break into Aurotos store/house and there's one in there. It also respawns every time you leave and come back. But you do have to be hidden and be quick because you do have to steal it

Answer (score 0):

Once you have 1 or more. You can do the dog eat duplication glitch. How you do that is drop the amount of mini nukes that stack so not 2 piles . The. Take dog eat a fair distance away then command him to pick up the mini nuke and when he is bending down to pick it up, pick it up at the same time. Then press X or A depending on the system to command him the. He will drop it if you only dropped 1 then just pick up that one mini nuke but If you have more than 1 mini nuke than drop your remaining mini nukes then quicksave. Leave the game the. Come back it will dupe it to the amount you had in your stack (Max:9) to a stack.

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure there is one in fort Hagen break into a room on the same level Kellogg is at and there is a Fat man a mini nuke lots of 10mm rounds and some other good stuff